# steam error : do not have enough disk space available to run this game please free up some disk space and try again

Tags: hard-drive, steam, disk-usage

I have installed steam but a message appears

> **Steam Error** : "**You do not have enough disk space available to run this game. Please free up some disk space and try again**"

whereas my hard drive its free 68,6 GB!!

Screenshot below.

[image]

Whats wrong? And how do I fix this?

Comment: How did you install steam? PlayOnLinux?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `df`

Comment: It seems that reboot helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This post is maybe a little bit old, but I got this problem these days and my answer could help someone.

I got this error message because my pc have two storage device (1 hdd and 1 ssd)
My secondary hdd wasn't mounted correctly so i umounted and mounted it again it worked!!
I think that steam tried to retrieve the games on my second hdd and didn't find it.

Hope that can help someone